# Solidity How to pass argument to constructor from client side

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, jquery

How to pass from argument to constructor function in solidity that can be received as msg.sender . This is my constructor code

```
constructor(uint256 _initialSupply)public{
   totalSupply = _initialSupply;
   balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
}
```

My client side code

```
initContract: function() {
$.getJSON('ErcToken.json', function(json, textStatus) {
  App.contracts.ErcToken = TruffleContract(json);
  App.contracts.ErcToken.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
  return App.rendor();
});
```

},

```
rendor: function(){

    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err,account){
        if(err === null){
          App.account = account;
          $("#").text(account);
        }
    });

    App.contracts.ErcToken.deployed().then(function(instance){
        return instance.balanceOf(App.account);
    }).then(function(balance){
        $("#").text(balance.toNumber());
    });

    return App.bindEvents();
  }
```

Here i'm always receiving balance as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor is only executed when the contract is deployed, afterwards it cannot be executed again.

If you want to arbitrarily assign tokens to any user you can add a mint function like this

```
function mint(uint amount) {
    totalSupply += amount;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
    emit Transfer(address(0x0), msg.sender, amount);
}
```

Comment: thank you , can you help me to identify this?
while transferring token from one to another metamask stuck at unknown network id . i'm using local network with ganache